# Using code generation to create similar Java Action classes

Tags: java, code-generation, netbeans-platform

I'm building a GUI application in Java using an application framework (Netbeans Platform) which requires a large amount of nearly identical classes to implement extremely similar `Action` classes. I've spent a lot of time attempting to generate these actions programmatically. Although I'm able to generate the Actions, the framework utilizes annotations during compile time to generate other internal cache/data files which I've been unable to reproduce using a programmatic approach.

I'm wondering if code generation tools are a better solution, or perhaps some custom annotations which wrap the framework annotations. Perhaps something like `Lombok`, or maybe a maven plugin. But don't know where to start and am not sure if this is even a good path to explore. Ideally, I think it would be great to define the actions in a data file and generate the java code at compile time.

The project is open source, [and a number of other actions are on github](https://github.com/winder/Universal-G-Code-Sender/tree/master/ugs-platform/ugs-platform-ugscore/src/main/java/com/willwinder/ugs/nbp/core/actions). Here is an example of what the template might look like, the pieces I would need to inject replaced with `{{string}}`, `{{code}}` and `{{int}}`:

```
// imports omitted

@ActionID(
        category = {{string}},
        id = {{string}})
@ActionRegistration(
        iconBase = {{string}},
        displayName = "resources.MessagesBundle#" + {{string}},
        lazy = false)
@ActionReferences({
        @ActionReference(
                path = {{string}},
                position = {{int}})
})
public final class {{string}} extends AbstractAction implements UGSEventListener {

    public static final String ICON_BASE = {{string}};

    private BackendAPI backend;

    public SoftResetAction() {
        this.backend = CentralLookup.getDefault().lookup(BackendAPI.class);
        this.backend.addUGSEventListener(this);

        putValue("iconBase", ICON_BASE);
        putValue(SMALL_ICON, ImageUtilities.loadImageIcon(ICON_BASE, false));
        putValue("menuText", {{string}});
        putValue(NAME, {{string}});

    }

    @Override
    public void UGSEvent(UGSEvent cse) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> setEnabled(isEnabled()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        {{code}}
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        {{code}}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why code generation over subclassing Actions? or using Actions factory methods?

Comment: @Sam the problem is that the application framework I'm using leverages annotations for its abstraction layer, so I would still have to duplicate the annotations in each file. Action factory methods is how I generate 50+ other actions, but unfortunately, they are not properly registered with the application framework due to the lack of annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You should try a code generator like Telosys ( http://www.telosys.org/ )

This tool is designed for this kind of situation, you just have to create a template for each type of repetitive class and launch the generation.

For more information see the templating principles : http://www.telosys.org/templates.html

Everything is free and open source, so you can reuse existing templates and adapt them according to your needs.

Some interresting posts about this tool :

- https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/
- https://dzone.com/articles/telosys-a-code-generation-tool-by-laurent-guerin

Answer (score -1):

You can design a public Action class for common using just like blow. This is only a section of sample code. If some modules has its own biz logical,  you can implements this PubAction to any subclass.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;


public abstract class PubAction
  extends AbstractAction
  implements AppEventListener
{
  protected ActionInterceptor interceptor;
  protected IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;
  protected IActionStatusJudge actionStatusJudge = null;

  public static final String TOOLBAR_SHOWNAME_KEY = "TOOLBAR_SHOWNAME_KEY";

  public PubAction()
  {
    setShowNameInToolbar(false);
  }

  public String getBtnName() {
    return (String)getValue("Name");
  }

  public void setBtnName(String btnName) {
    putValue("Name", btnName);
  }

  public void setCode(String code)
  {
    putValue("Code", code);
  }

  public void handleEvent(AppEvent event)
  {
    updateStatus();
  }

  public void updateStatus()
  {
    boolean isEnable = isActionEnable();
    setEnabled(getActionStatusJudge() == null ? isEnable : getActionStatusJudge().isActionEnable(this, isEnable));
  }

  protected boolean isActionEnable() {
    return true;
  }

  public void setShowNameInToolbar(boolean isShow)
  {
    putValue("TOOLBAR_SHOWNAME_KEY", isShow ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Logger.debug("Entering " + getClass().toString() + ".actionPerformed");
    beforeDoAction();
    try
    {
      if ((interceptor == null) || (interceptor.beforeDoAction(this, e)))
      {
        try
        {
          doAction(e);
          if (interceptor != null) {
            interceptor.afterDoActionSuccessed(this, e);
          }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          if ((interceptor == null) || (interceptor.afterDoActionFailed(this, e, ex)))
          {
            if (getExceptionHandler() != null)
            {
              processExceptionHandler(ex);
            }
            else if ((ex instanceof RuntimeException))
            {
              throw ((RuntimeException)ex);
            }

            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      Logger.debug("Leaving " + getClass().toString() + ".actionPerformed");
    }
  }



  protected void processExceptionHandler(Exception ex)
  {
    new ExceptionHandlerUtil().processErrorMsg4SpecialAction(this, getExceptionHandler(), ex);
  }

  protected void beforeDoAction()
  {
    Method[] ms = getClass().getMethods();
    for (Method m : ms)
    {
      Class<?> clazz = m.getReturnType();
      if (AbstractUIAppModel.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        try
        {
          AbstractUIAppModel model = (AbstractUIAppModel)m.invoke(this, null);
          if (model == null)
            return;
          LoginContext ctx = model.getContext();
          if (ctx == null)
            break;
          ShowStatusBarMsgUtil.showStatusBarMsg("", ctx);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          Logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          Logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
          Logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public abstract void doAction(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) throws Exception;

  public ActionInterceptor getInterceptor()
  {
    return interceptor;
  }

  public void setInterceptor(ActionInterceptor interceptor) {
    this.interceptor = interceptor;
  }

  public IExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
    return exceptionHandler;
  }

  public void setExceptionHandler(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
    this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
  }

  public IActionStatusJudge getActionStatusJudge() {
    return actionStatusJudge;
  }

  public void setActionStatusJudge(IActionStatusJudge actionStatusJudge) {
    this.actionStatusJudge = actionStatusJudge;
  }
}
```